# Python error when trying to multiply two `float`s

Tags: python, variables

I am working on a simple routine in Python which conditionally applies a discount to a monetary amount so long as it is above a certain threshold:

```
money = input("how much are you paying ")

discount = 0.2
num = 20

float(money)

payment = money*discount

if money > num:
    print("you are paying " + money)
else:
    print("you are paying " + payment )
```

However, the above code is not working as expected with an error thrown from the line:

`payment = money*discount`

Could anyone please advise as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to do `money = float(money)` and use `str(money)` and `str(payment)` in the `print` statements

Comment: @not_speshal is correct. You never set `money` as a float.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't assigning `float(money)` to anything.

With minimal changes to your existing code, try:

```
money = float(input("how much are you paying "))
discount = 0.2
num = 20
payment = money*discount

if money > num:
    print("you are paying " + str(money))
else:
    print("you are paying " + str(payment))
```

Alternatively, you can reduce the last four lines of your code to a single line using f-strings:

```
money = float(input("how much are you paying "))
discount = 0.2
num = 20
payment = money*discount

print(f"you are paying {money if money>num else payment}")
```

Comment: Or do `print("you are paying", money)` or my personal preference `print(f"you are paying {money}")`

Comment: I prefer f-strings any day too. But seeing the level of the question, I thought it might be easier for OP to understand if I make minimal changes to the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can either directly take in the input as a float like this.

```
money = float(input("how much are you paying "))
```

Or assign the converted value into the `money` variable.

```
money = float(money)
```

You also need to modify the print statements if you are not changing the type of `money` and `payment` to `str` before concatenating them.

```
if money > num:
    print("you are paying " , money)
else:
    print("you are paying " , payment )
```

Answer (score 0):

1: You need to cast `money` to `float` so you can perform mathematical operations on it such as multiplication, you can do that by

```py
money = float(input("..."))
```

2: You are adding a number to a string, You can't do `print("you are paying " + money)` because `"you are paying"` is a string type and `money` should be a number (after you follow my first comment), instead, you can remove the last space in the string so it would be `"you are paying"` instead of `"you are paying "` and then you can use `print`'s ability to concatenate items with a space in between: `print("you are paying", money)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate between a string and int type.

Try this and see for yourself :

```
money = input("how much are you paying ")
print(type(money))
...
```

So, you need to "cast" the variable "money".

```
money = input("how much are you paying ")

discount = 0.2
num = 20
cast_money = float(money)

payment = cast_money*discount

if cast_money > num:
    print("you are paying " + money)
else:
    print("you are paying " + payment )
```

Comment: You also need to cast `payment` to `str` for printing